# How to run the python script without copying to console from script?

Tags: python

I am newbie in Python :) and i like it as it very simple and friendly.

How to run the python script without copying to console from script ? For example, in R, using Ctrl+R runs the current line or the selection.

Comment: `python script.py` in a terminal. Not the python shell (e.g. IDLE) but a plain terminal that comes with your OS.

Comment: yeah, but this way one needs to write the entire program (that one want to execute) and then do the python script.py command. However if you want to run one line at a time and do not want to copy the code from IDLE module to console, is there any short cut? I use R and there we can just select the line and hit Ctrl+R, it works. Actually this way its faster to debug the code as well.

Comment: Maybe something like a jupyter notebook is what you'd want? http://jupyter.org/

Comment: Not that I know of. That sounds like an editor feature rather than a language one. Check out `pdb`, it may interest you.

Comment: @AlexHall, right. Its editor feature.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i meant same.

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt

```
>cmd
```

To run the complete python script:

```
python <script.py>
```

To run the python script line by line or with other debug options like break points, use the following command:

```
python -m pdb <script.py>
```

You can use following letters for different commands

```
n: next line
s: get inside function
b <line number> : create break point
c : contunue
```